# How to use vmov to set value from s0 to r0?

Tags: arm

In arm instructions,I can use

vmov r0, s0 /*assume the value of s0 is 100 */

to mov the value from s0 to r0,and r0 is 100 now.

But when I do this

vmov s0, r0 /*assume the value of r0 is 100 */

to mov the value from r0 to s0, I got s0 as 0,not 100.

Could someone tell me how to set the value correctly?

Answer (score 2):

`vmov` is a bit-wise copy.  If you have 100 as an integer in r0 and want to convert it to 32-bit floating point in s0 you need to `vmov` it to an VFP register and then `vcvt` it to floating point format, for example:

```
vmov s0, r0
vcvt.f32.s32 s0, s0 ; convert signed int -> 32-bit float
```

Similarly for covering the other way:

```
vcvt.s32.f32 s0, s0 ; convert 32-bit float -> signed int
vmov r0, s0
```

Details are in the ARM Architecture Reference Manual (ARM ARM):  http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0406c/index.html (needs registration)